# Как изменить формат даты в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В таблице есть данные формата: `datetime64[ns]`.
При этом, строка имеет вид: `02.03.2020  0:00:00`.

Как можно преобразовать весь столбец к формату даты: `02.03.2020`?

Comment: `df['date'].dt.date` ?

Answer (score 4):

воспользуйтесь [Series.dt.floor()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df["date"] = df["date"].dt.floor("D")
```